# Saving TextView to a String and sending value to another activity

Tags: java, android

So i am trying to have a value from a textView saved to a string and sent to another activity where the value will be used to find a location. So i am using long and lat. These values are coming from a MYSQL server using PHP and display correctly. But when i try to go to a new activity i get an error:

Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.CharSequence android.widget.TextView.getText()' on a null object reference

Here is my code to show what i have tried the error comes at Latit.getText().toString() and Longit.getText().toString()

```
public void goDirect(View v){

    TextView Latit = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvLatitude);
    TextView Longit = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvLongitude);

    Intent passData = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), testDataPass.class);

    passData.putExtra("Latitude",Latit.getText().toString());
    passData.putExtra("Longitude", Longit.getText().toString());

    startActivity(passData);
}
```

I have also tried:

```
 public void goDirect(View v){

    TextView Latit = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvLatitude);
    TextView Longit = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvLongitude);

    String Lat = Latit.getText().toString();
    String Lon = Longit.getText().toString(); 

    Intent passData = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), testDataPass.class);

    passData.putExtra("Latitude",Lat);
    passData.putExtra("Longitude", Lon);

    startActivity(passData);
}
```

Both give the same error at the same place, i have done something like this for another use but have not been able to get it to work this time. I have looked around and other similar questions/answers have not helped.So any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: show your layout, you have error because your textView not exist or not called in your activity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, i would recommend you structure your activity like this. Your TextViews are now initialised immediately after the activity is created and has the added benefit of having all your views declared in the same location as appose to dotted around the app in various functions among other benefits.

Following this, the only reason you'll get a null on the getText() is because the TextView you are referencing could not be found. You need to go into the XML for your activity and ensure that you have a TextView with ID: "@+id/tvLatitude" & the same for Longitude

```
package my.package;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private TextView Latit;
    private TextView Longit;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Latit = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvLatitude);
        Longit = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvLongitude);

        //Presume you are using an XML based OnClick

    }

    public void goDirect(View v){
        Intent passData = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), testDataPass.class);
        passData.putExtra("Latitude",Latit.getText().toString());
        passData.putExtra("Longitude", Longit.getText().toString());
        startActivity(passData);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you inflate your view (`onCreateView()`) you can call

`TextView Latit = (TextView) yourInflatedView.findViewById(R.id.tvLatitude);`

The error you get means that the view could not be found or you call `getText()` before initializing the view.

Answer (score 0):

you have error because your textView not exist or not called in your activity

if your View v have this textView you need do like this:

```
public void goDirect(View v){

TextView Latit = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.tvLatitude);
TextView Longit = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.tvLongitude);

String Lat = Latit.getText().toString();
String Lon = Longit.getText().toString(); 

Intent passData = new Intent(activity.context, testDataPass.class);

        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("Latitude",Latit.getText().toString());
        bundle.putString("Longitude", Longit.getText().toString());
        passData.putExtras(bundle);

startActivity(passData);
}
```

and access to data in your testDataPass activity

```
        Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
                if (bundle != null) {
                //you have data

                String Latitude = bundle.getString("Latitude");
                String Longitude = bundle.getString("Longitude");

           }else{
                //you dont have data
              }
```